# When I change first item components,Last item is effected

Tags: android, listview, scroll, row

I have a custom row that contains a text view and 3 Clickable Image Views.
onClick on any one of the ImageView this Image changes to another one.

My problem is that when I click on Image1 on row1, the image changed in both row1 and row9 as well, and when I click on row2, the image changed in row2 and row10 as well.. so On. I don't know why.

But I think it it about scrolling.

This is `getView()` in my Adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (vi == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comprow, null);
    }
    TextView text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
    text.setText(data.get(position));

    return vi;
}
```

And this is OnClick function for the first ImageView
        public void one(View v) {

```
    RelativeLayout row = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
    ImageView im1 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.one);
    ImageView im2 = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.two);
    ImageView im3 = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.three);

    im1.setImageResource(R.drawable.c0);    
    im2.setImageResource(R.drawable.b1);
    im3.setImageResource(R.drawable.b2);

    simpleAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't use of id, your changed repeat in all row because you worked with position,then you must set id to each row that create in `getView()`, now if you have a few choice, you can handle with array of integer with size of list, that in default is equal 0 then if you press one row the value of row changed, then in show image check the value of this row, if is zero then let in default, else check the value and select image that you want to show, I hope that you understand my word

Comment: unfortunately I can't get your solution

Comment: Yea I got it.But I don't think it is suitable for me.
As in my app I disabled the row selection (I do nothing when the user select specific row)
I do some modification when he/she clicks on any image of the imageview in the row.
Yes I have limited number of images only 3 images in each row.on click on any one I replace it with another one.